# Adding a GridView inside an ExpandableListView

Tags: android, arraylist, gridview, imageview, expandablelistview

In the first time , only ExpandableListView , but my Client ask me to add GridView inside ExpandableListView , so this is my code :

```
  private List<String> Group;
  private List<List<String>> Child;
  private List<String> Child_1;
  private List<String> Child_2;
  private List<String> Child_3;
  private List<List<Integer>> ChildPicture;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Group = new ArrayList<String>();
    Group.add("SPORT");
    Group.add("Healthy");
    Group.add("Measure");

    Child_1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Child_1.add("Swimming");
    Child_1.add("Biking");
    Child_1.add("Hiking");

    Child_2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Child_2.add("Walking");
    Child_2.add("Running");

    Child_3 =new ArrayList<String>();
    Child_3.add("Measure");

    Child = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    Child.add(Child_1);
    Child.add(Child_2);
    Child.add(Child_3);

    List<Integer> ChildPic_1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ChildPic_1.add(R.drawable.ic_swimming);
    ChildPic_1.add(R.drawable.ic_bike);
    ChildPic_1.add(R.drawable.ic_hiking);

    List<Integer> ChildPic_2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ChildPic_2.add(R.drawable.ic_walk);
    ChildPic_2.add(R.drawable.ic_running);

    List<Integer> ChildPic_3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ChildPic_3.add(R.drawable.ic_matters);

    ChildPicture = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    ChildPicture.add(ChildPic_1);
    ChildPicture.add(ChildPic_2);
    ChildPicture.add(ChildPic_3);

    ExpandableListView elv = findViewById(R.id.expenview);
    elv.setAdapter(new MyExpandableAdapter(Main2Activity.this));
    elv.setGroupIndicator(null);
   }

   class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{
    private Context context;
    private int[] groupLogo = new int[] { R.drawable.fitness, R.drawable.walking, R.drawable.temp };

    public MyExpandableAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return Group.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return Child.get(groupPosition).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return Group.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return Child.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GroupHolder groupHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.expandablelist_group, null);
        }
        groupHolder = new GroupHolder();
        groupHolder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
        groupHolder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_icon);
        groupHolder.text.setText(Group.get(groupPosition));
        groupHolder.imageview.setImageResource(groupLogo[groupPosition]);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
        }
        GridView gv = (GridView) convertView;
        gv.setAdapter(new ImageViewAdapter(Main2Activity.this, Child, ChildPicture));
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}

class GroupHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public ImageView imageview;
}

class ImageViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context context;
    private List<List<String>> Child;
    private List<List<Integer>> ChildPicture;

    public ImageViewAdapter(Context context, List<List<String>> child, List<List<Integer>> childPicture) {
        this.context = context;
        Child = child;
        ChildPicture = childPicture;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Child.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return Child.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
        }
        TextView itemHolderText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        ImageView itemHolderImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
        itemHolderText.setText(Child.get(position).toString()); //Strong?
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

then I get the result like this :

[GridView with text and ImageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxcty.png)

In fact , Sport item will show 3 items , like Swimming , Biking and Hiking,
not all show in same item. I don't know how to fix it , please Help me , Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ExpandableListView with ListView children, it used **getChildrenCount()** to know how many child views need to create and **getChildView()** creates single item view for single child of a group.

But with GridLayout/GridView/ViewPager as child view, then there is **ONLY ONE** child view [so getChildrenCount() return 1] and so getChildView() handles the **WHOLE CHILD LIST OF A GROUP**.

Try below adapters for your ExpandableListView and GridView:

```
class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int[] groupLogo = new int[] { R.drawable.fitness, R.drawable.walking, R.drawable.temp };

    public MyExpandableAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return Group.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1; //Changed
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return Group.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return Child.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GroupHolder groupHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.expandablelist_group, null);
        }
        groupHolder = new GroupHolder();
        groupHolder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
        groupHolder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_icon);
        groupHolder.text.setText(Group.get(groupPosition));
        groupHolder.imageview.setImageResource(groupLogo[groupPosition]);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
        }
        GridView gv = (GridView) convertView;
        gv.setAdapter(new ImageViewAdapter(Main2Activity.this, Child.get(groupPosition), ChildPicture.get(groupPosition))); //Changed
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}

class GroupHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public ImageView imageview;
}

class ImageViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> Child; //Changed
    private List<Integer> ChildPicture; //Changed

    public ImageViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> child, List<Integer> childPicture) { //Changed
        this.context = context;
        this.Child = child; //Changed
        this.ChildPicture = childPicture; //Changed
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Child.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return Child.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
        }
        TextView itemHolderText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        ImageView itemHolderImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
        itemHolderText.setText(Child.get(position).toString()); //Strong?
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. Final , you fix my question. Thanks again.

Comment: May I ask  you one question ? If I want to R.drawable.xxx can be onclicked , what do I do ?
For Example :
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    switch(xxx) {
       case R.drawable.ic_swimming:

    }

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use Below Library or  get some Idea from it to make your own implementation  for `ExpandableListView` with `GridView`.

This example project is an attempt at a simple implementation of sectioned, expandable, grid `RecyclerView`

by using `GridLayoutManager` to achieve the functionality.

`SectionedExpandableLayoutHelper` class gets the data, puts it in required format and passes it to the `SectionedExpandableGridAdapter`

Helper class created allows the addition/removal of a whole section altogether and also provides with the facility to add/remove individual items from an existing section

[SectionedExpandableGridRecyclerView-master](https://github.com/SelvaGaneshM/SectionedExpandableGridRecyclerView-master)